# Parsing json GitHub api with Python

Tags: python, json, github, github-api

Having difficulty parsing json from GitHub api. I'm trying to populate a team with all the repos from an organisation. I'm using myteamname to obtain the teamid required for the loop which populates the team with the repo names.

```
import json
import requests

mytokenid = "xxx"
myorg = "xxx"
myteamname = "xxx"


headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token %s' % mytokenid,
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/{0}/teams/{1}'.format(myorg, myteamname), headers=headers)
teamidjson = json.loads(response.text)
myteamid = teamidjson(['id'])

g = Github(tokenid)
for repo in g.get_organization(myorg).get_repos():
    myreponame = repo.name
    response = requests.put('https://api.github.com/teams/{0}/repos/{1}/{2}'.format(myteamid, myorg, myreponame), headers=headers)
```

I get this error message

```
  File "githubteam.py", line 74, in <module>
    myteamid = teamidjson(['id'])
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The second half with the for loop works only if I hardcode the teamid. What I want to do use is to extract the teamid from the team name and use that instead. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you goingbto add that to the question itself? You should also add the JSON from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myteamid = teamidjson(['id'])`

That seems to be causing the error. The correct way to access the `id` key is:

`myteamid = teamidjson['id']`

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
myteamid = teamidjson['id']

# you can also use this
myteamid = teamidjson.get('id', None) # it will default to None if id doesn't exist...
```